# How do I customise url in RedirectView

Tags: django

I'm using Django 1.5, trying to capture a param from url, then use this param to query an article id and redirect user to that article.

Can I not specify new url in `url.py` and do something like below? But it just appends the url I want to use to the end of current url

url.py

```
url(r'^external/(?P<external_id>\d+)/$', myView.as_view(), name='external-view')
```

views.py

```
class MyView(RedirectView):
    def get_redirect_url(self, **kwargs):
        external_id = kwargs['external_id']
        article_id = Article.objects.get(external_id=external_id).id
        domain = Site.objects.get_current().domain
        new_url = '{}/article/{}'.format(domain, article_id)
        return new_url
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to get the external redirect working you have to include 'http://' or 'https://' before the domain. So you could do either of these two options:

1. Whenever saving `Site` objects, make sure the `domain` attribute starts with either 'http://' or 'https://'
2. You can hardcode it: `new_url = 'http://{}/article/{}'.format(domain, article_id)` but you would need to know before hand if it's http or https